# JSON text and variable count

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am reading like this...

```
NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];  

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:fileContent error:nil];  

// getting the data from inside of "menu"  

NSString *message = (NSString *) [data objectForKey:@"message"];
 NSString *name = (NSString *) [data objectForKey:@"name"];

NSArray *messagearray = [data objectForKey:@"message"];
NSArray *namearray    = [data objectForKey:@"name"];


NSDictionary* Dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:message forKeys:name];

for (NSString* Key in [Dictionary allKeys]){
    NSLog(@"%@ %@",Key,[Dictionary objectForKey:Key]);

}
```

...this JSON file...

```
{"message":["Untitled1a","Untitled2a","Untitled3a"],"name":    ["Untitled1b","Untitled2b","Untitled3b"]}
```

...this is the result...

```
Untitled3b Untitled3a
2012-05-12 11:31:17.983 Quick Homework[721:f803] Untitled1b Untitled1a
2012-05-12 11:31:17.983 Quick Homework[721:f803] Untitled2b Untitled2a
```

...but for each pair (Untitled 1b 2b) I would like to alloc two UITextFields, witch display the correspondent text...

I tried using this method:

```
for (NSString *string in messagearray){

}do{
    NSLog(@"happt = %i", b);
    b++;

}

while(b == b);

//While loop
while (b == b ) {
    NSLog(@"x = %i", b);
    b++;
}

}
```

I would like to count the objects in the array in order to repeat an alloc code for UITextField that number of times, and display the text accordingly, but I am not able. Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use -count?

`b = [messagearray count]`

---

To directly answer your question:

```
b = 0;
for (id item in messagearray)
    b++;
```